# PANDAS: Converting all datetimes in column to another format

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a Pandas dataframe containing a datetime column, in which all the values are formatted like this: 
`25/09/15 12:00:00`. I'd like to reformat this field in all the rows, in order to match this format: `25.09.15 12:00`.

Here some sample data:

```
Date              | Value
25/08/15 12:00:00 | 49.0
25/08/15 13:00:00 | 49.5
```

The date column datatype is string.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Some sample data in your post would be better. I assume the type of the column with date is a string, so you'll need column names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.dt.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) to format datetime

```py
df
                 Date  Value
0 2015-08-25 12:00:00   49.0
1 2015-08-25 13:00:00   49.5

df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y.%m.%d %H:%M')
df
               Date  Value
0  2015.08.25 12:00   49.0
1  2015.08.25 13:00   49.5
```

if column type is `str` than you need to convert first to datetime

```py
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
```